# Como saber qual div é mostrada na tela com javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, aplicação-web

Tenho um site com varias divs, e preciso que quando a tela chegue em determinada div, aconteça uma ação, mas não sei qual evento de javascript ou jquery é responsável por isso.

Exemplo:

```html
<div id='1'>
  div1
</div>
<div id='2'>
  div2
</div>
```

Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Tente detalhar melhor o que você quer fazer.

Answer (score 2):

Como estou trabalhando muito com scroll nos últimos dias, estava na ponta dos dedos, segue abaixo um exemplo simples, basta implementar variáveis de controle para verificar se a ação já foi disparada e evitar repetição...

```js
// armazena o scrolltop do elemento que deseja aguardar
var scrollTopoffset = $('#dois').offset().top - $(window).height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > scrollTopoffset) {
  // rolagem chegou ao elemento
    alert('#dois apareceu!');
  }
});
```

```css
#um {
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 500px
}
#dois {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 500px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='um'>
  div1
</div>
<div id='dois'>
  div2
</div>
```