# Verificando se um elemento está visível ou não na página

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Eu tenho os seguintes botões:

**Primeiro botão:**

```
<button id="modal-btn" class="button btn-cart btn-verde-claro"> <span>Comprar</span> </button>
```

**Segundo botão:**

```
<div class="btn-comprar-fixed-mobile" id="btn-comprar-fixed-mobile" style="display: none">
    <button class="button btn-cart btn-verde-claro"><span>Comprar</span></button>
</div>
```

Eu queria que quando o primeiro botão aparecesse, o segundo não aparecesse e vice versa. Quando o segundo aparecer na tela, o primeiro ficasse escondido.

Fiz a função em jQuery usando o `.is(':visible')`, porém não deu certo, pois eu queria ver se o elemento estava sendo exibido na tela, não se está com `display: none` ou `display: block`.

**Código da função:**

```
$j(window).scroll(function() { 
   console.log('fazendo');  
   if($j('#modal-btn').is(':visible')){
       console.log('if');
       $j('#btn-comprar-fixed-mobile').css('display','none');
   } else{
       console.log('else');
       $j('#btn-comprar-fixed-mobile').css('display','block');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode verificar se ele esta na tela verificando o scroll.

Como os botões irão sumir e aparecer, vou utilizar a div para definir quando ele deve aparecer, você vai fazer da mesma forma na sua pagina, colocando as divs onde os botões estão.

```
<div class="area1">
  <button id="btn1">Comprar</button>
</div>
<div class="area2">
    <button id="btn2">Comprar</button>
</div>
```

Criei este código css para que a pagina possa ter um scroll:

```
body{
  background-color:#000;
}
.area1{
  background-color:#a00;
  height: 1000px;
}
.area2{
  background-color:#005;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

E o seguinte código:

```
$(function(){
  var area1 = $('.area1').offset().top - $(window).height();
  var area2 = $('.area2').offset().top - $(window).height();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > area1) {
      $('#btn1').css('display','block');
      $('#btn2').css('display','none');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > area2) {
        $('#btn2').css('display','block');
      $('#btn1').css('display','none');
    }    
  });
});
```

Assim ele consegue pegar se ele esta ou não na tela através do scroll.

Resultado: https://jsfiddle.net/pjqxrgwu/

Creditos: [Como saber qual div é mostrada na tela com javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151184/como-saber-qual-div-%C3%A9-mostrada-na-tela-com-javascript)

Comment: Acho que ele quis dizer que o primeiro botão é fixo, e quando aparecesse ou segundo, o primeiro sumisse e vive-versa... aliás, o segundo que é fixo rs

Comment: @dvd isso mesmo. Mas consegui fazer funcionar a partir desse código, somente alterei algumas coisas na função.